# Add new column with value based on other column starting character

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Using pandas I want to be fill DVZ column with data (data1, data2, etc..) based on starting sting of column DV2  for example if start with 9 will add data1 to DVZ first raw and second if start with 7 will add data2 if start with 7 will be data3 in DVZ

I am trying with dew['DVZ']

```
[dew["DV0"].astype('str').str.startswith("9")] = "Sin"
```

but I'm not able to get the desired result. Appreciate if any one can help me

| DV1 | DV2 | DVZ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9412 | 941 | new data |
| 9434 | 911 | new data |
| 9412 | 717 | new data |
| 3114 | 311 | new data |
| 6314 | 631 | new data |
| 6622 | 662 | new data |

Here's my desired result:

| DV1 | DV2 | DVZ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9412 | 941 | data1 |
| 9434 | 911 | data1 |
| 9412 | 717 | data2 |
| 3114 | 311 | data3 |
| 6314 | 631 | data4 |
| 6622 | 662 | data4 |

Comment: If the next record of your dataframe is 962, what should be the output: data5 or data1?

Comment: the output is data1  the output is always same associated with starting sting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
c = df['DV2'].astype(str).str[0]
df['DVZ'] = 'data' + c.ne(c.shift()).cumsum().astype(str)
print(df)

# Output
    DV1  DV2    DVZ
0  9412  941  data1
1  9434  911  data1
2  9412  717  data2
3  3114  311  data3
4  6314  631  data4
5  6622  662  data4
```

**Update**

> Because DV2 is start with 9 I will add the word data1 when start with 7 I will put date2 with start with 4 I put data3 and so on.

Create a mapping dict:

```
M = {'9': 'data1', '7': 'data2', '3': 'data3', '6': 'data4'} # and so on
df['DVZ'] = df['DV2'].astype(str).str[0].map(M)
print(df)

# Output
    DV1  DV2    DVZ
0  9412  941  data1
1  9434  911  data1
2  9412  717  data2
3  3114  311  data3
4  6314  631  data4
5  6622  662  data4
```

Comment: my by my question is not clear ..because DV2 is start with 9 I will add the word data1  when start with 7 I will put date2 with start with 4 I put data3  and so on

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: Thanks for you help. it worked with your update... I just had to strip leading space.